# How to get original string data back from TFRecordData

Tags: python, string, tensorflow, tfrecord

I followed Tensorflow guide to save my string data using:

```
def _create_string_feature(values):
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[values.encode('utf-8')]))
```

I also used `["tf.string", "FixedLenFeature"]` as my feature original type, and `"tf.string"` as my feature convert type.

However, during my training when I run my session and I create iterators, my string feature for a batch size of 2 (for example: ['food fruit', 'cupcake food' ]) would be like below. The problem is that this list is of size 1, and not 2 (batch_size=2), why instances in one batch are stick together rather than being splitted?

```
[b'food fruit' b'cupcake food']
```

For my other features which are int or float, they are bumpy arrays of shape (batch_size, feature_len) which are fine but not sure why string features are not separated in a single batch?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you take a look at [this Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1xU_MJ3R8oj8YYYi-VI_WJTU3hD1OpAB7#scrollTo=jebRBb07ol4E)? There's a section on writing and reading Text data with TFRecords. Copy the code parts and see if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This will convert a `BytesList` or `bytes_list` string object to a string:

```
my_bytes_list_object.value[0].decode()
```

Or, in the case one is extracting the string from a TFRecord Example object:

```
my_example.features.feature['MyFeatureName'].bytes_list.value[0].decode()
```

From what I can see, `bytes_list` returns a `BytesList` object, from which we can read the `value` field.  This will return a `RepeatedScalarContainer`, which operates like a simple `list` object.  In fact, if you wrap it with the `list()` operation it will convert it to a list.  However, instead we can just access it as if it were a list and use `[0]` to get the zeroth item.  The returned item is a `bytes` array, which can be converted to a standard `str` object with the `decode()` method.