# How to split a bytes array on b''

Tags: python

I have arrays like following:

```
x = [b'ab ab bc' b'rd rd kh']
```

Fo some reason I don't know why there is not a comma between first byte encoded string `(b'ab ab bc')` and the second one `(b'rd rd kh')`.
I wonder how I can split these to have a list like:

```
x = [b'ab ab bc', b'rd rd kh']
# decode
res = [i.decode('utf-8') for i in x]
```

I want the result be like: `res = ['ab ab bc', 'rd rd kh']`

Comment: Your example looks ok to me. What's not working about it?

Answer (score 2):

[Adjacent `bytes` literals in the source code are automatically concatenated](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation):

> Multiple adjacent string or bytes literals (delimited by whitespace), possibly using different quoting conventions, are allowed, and their meaning is the same as their concatenation. Thus, `"hello" 'world'` is equivalent to `"helloworld"`.

So source code like:

```
 x = [b'ab ab bc' b'rd rd kh']
```

is *exactly* equivalent to (compiles to identical byte code):

```
 x = [b'ab ab bcrd rd kh']
```

To split them, you need to actually add the comma(s) as you've shown:

```
 x = [b'ab ab bc', b'rd rd kh']
               # ^ added comma
```

with `decode`ing done exactly as you've shown. There's no way to skip the comma without making the whole thing a string and writing custom parsing code, which is a lot more painful than just adding the comma.

Comment: You worded it much better :p

Comment: Is there a automatic way to have comma there and split them? I have a lot of such list with different string and I want to split them not manually.

Comment: @FaezeBr.: Not any solution that wouldn't be harder than just fixing the code properly (as I mention in my last paragraph). You can't just opt out of Python's syntax without writing a new language or a full preprocessor (way outside the scope of StackOverflow answers). Again, to be 100% clear: **By the time this code even *begins* running, the compiler has thrown away all information about the separate literals, such that it's *exactly* equivalent to having written only one; you can't split them because there is no remaining information on where they used to be split**.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, I got these array out of using tfrecord (tensorflow). I explained it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60177218/how-to-get-original-string-data-back-from-tfrecorddata) and more in detailed [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36739). I didn't get any response of how to solve that and that's why I thought maybe I need to just split them myself.

Comment: @FaezeBr.: I honestly can't see how or if it's generating `[b'ab ab bc' b'rd rd kh']`, as in all your cases, we don't have a [MCVE] to replicate it. My guess would be you're receiving a data type with a custom `__repr__` that omits the commas, but you claim you know the length to be one, which would contradict that. As is, no one can help you because no one can replicate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason there is no comma in that list is because of pythons implicit string construction. x is in fact a list with a single byte string in it `b'ab ab bcrd rd kh'`.

Splitting it is not possible that was as you have seen, you could split it between bcrd but I dont think thats what you want to do

Comment: Do you mean there is no simple way of splitting them using some code?

Comment: No, no simple way. If you know exactly what the input would be then yes its easy but im assuming that is just sample input and it will change unpredictably

Comment: You should not be storing arrays/lists in that way, the comma exists and separates elements for a reason

Comment: ,I got these array out of using tfrecord (tensorflow). I explained it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60177218/how-to-get-original-string-data-back-from-tfrecorddata) and more in detailed [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36739). I didn't get any response of how to solve that and that's why I thought maybe I need to just split them myself.

Comment: Looking at that tensor flow post it looks like the same issue, your strings are being concentrated together and read out together. If you know how they were read in through you can split them as they're read out with string.split('string to split with') which will split a string into a list creating a new element every time it encounters 'string to split'