# How to skip some records from tf.data.TFRecordDataset based on their labels?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, filter, tfrecord

Currently I am working on a training application for ResNet. The project itself was not begun by me, but by other developers. I have a huge storage full of source photos, thousands of files, 8 TB in total. All photos are divided by hundreds of classes. Sometimes I need to include only one part of classes, other time I need to exclude them and use other classes, and so on. Every time I need to build a dataset at first, and as a result of the dataset creation I get a bunch of `tfrecord` files, then I can start a model training. I want to optimize this process: build a large dataset with all the photos and all the classes and after that filter (exclude/include) classes at the training time by it's labels.

I have found a `filter()` method and I understand how to use it with a simple dataset:

```
def filter(x):
    if x < -2:
        print('x < -2')
        return True
    elif x > 2:
        print('x > 2')
        return True
    else:
        print('False')
        return False

d = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
d = d.filter(filter)
```

The first interesting question for me here is that it seems TF somehow optimizes a function. Output:

```
x < -2
x > 2
False
```

So not every `print` statement is executed. But the filter works as expected and I get `[-4, -3, 3, 4]`
`

Anyway I cannot understand how to filter a dataset by a class label. The dataset consists of records, each record consists of two images and a class label. Here is my testing code:

```
def test_filter_function(x):
    feature_description = {
        'image_raw': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string, default_value=''),
        'image2_raw': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string, default_value=''),
        'label': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string, default_value='')
    }
    print(x)
    parsed = tf.io.parse_single_example(x, feature_description)
    print(parsed['image_raw'])
    print(parsed['label'])
    return True

dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(list_of_tfrecord_files)
dataset = dataset.filter(test_filter_function)
```

And the output is:

```
Tensor("args_0:0", shape=(), dtype=string)
Tensor("ParseSingleExample/ParseSingleExample:1", shape=(), dtype=string)
Tensor("ParseSingleExample/ParseSingleExample:2", shape=(), dtype=string)
```

What is "args_0:0"?
Why both, `parsed['image_raw']` and `print(parsed['label'])` have the same Tensor type and it's `dtype` is a `string`?
How can I get a class label in a form of python string type and how to check is it in a set of enabled classes or not?
Is it possible and how to exclude records which labels not in the set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The first interesting question for me here is that it seems TF somehow optimizes a function.

So in eager execution, TensorFlow would only run the function the first when it generates an optimised computation graph, after which it only uses TensorFlow functions. See [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/basics#graphs_and_tffunction)

> What is "args_0:0"? Why both, parsed['image_raw'] and print(parsed['label']) have the same Tensor type and it's dtype is a string? How can I get a class label in a form of python string type and how to check is it in a set of enabled classes or not? Is it possible and how to exclude records which labels not in the set?

"`args_0:0`" is just the tensor's generated name. Images are serialised as strings in records, you can convert them back using `image.numpy()`, similarly for the label you can use `byteslist` to decode back. See [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60177218/how-to-get-original-string-data-back-from-tfrecorddata).

So, if you want to filter, you need to make sure that you either wrap your function with `tf.py_funcion` or even better, only use `tf.functions`, such that your code can be run with eager execution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you mean something like that:
`parsed = tf.io.parse_single_example(x, feature_description)` `print(parsed['label'].value[0].decode())` The result: `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'value'`

Comment: @AlexeyShaferov parsed['label'].bytes_list.value[0].decode()

Comment: I have changed filter to use `tf.py_function`. `parsed['label'].bytes_list.value[0].decode()` result is `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'bytes_list'` But if I do just `print(parsed['label'])` I get this: `Tensor("ParseSingleExample/ParseSingleExample:2", shape=(), dtype=string)`, `tf.Tensor(b'5300', shape=(), dtype=string)`, `tf.Tensor(b'5700', shape=(), dtype=string)`, `tf.Tensor(b'8940', shape=(), dtype=string)`... It looks optimistic! But what is the first record? What is `ParseSingleExample/ParseSingleExample`? Do I need to return True or False for it?

Comment: Seems I can get the actual value with use of `tf.get_static_value(parsed['label'])`. It works, but a little bit slow. Anyway, what is the first element? What the filter function must return for it? `Tensor("ParseSingleExample/ParseSingleExample:2", shape=(), dtype=string)` = `None`, `tf.Tensor(b'5300', shape=(), dtype=string)` = `b'5300'`, `tf.Tensor(b'8940', shape=(), dtype=string)` = `b'8940'`